# adding rows with matching user entered product code to jatable from sql server

Tags: sql-server, jtable, billing

```
 Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
      if (con!= null) {
         System.out.println("Connected");
      }
       String sql="select product_name, price from inventorytable where product_code=?";
       PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
       pst.setString(1,ProductCode.getText());
       ResultSet rs= pst.executeQuery();
       ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata=rs.getMetaData();
       int columns=rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
       DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel();  
       Vector columns_name=new Vector();
       Vector data_rows=new Vector();
       for(int i=1; i<=columns;i++){
       columns_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
       }
       dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns_name);
       while(rs.next()){
        data_rows=new Vector();
        for(int j=1;j<=columns;j++){
         data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
        }
        dtm.addRow(data_rows);
    }
    BillTable.setModel(dtm);

    }
```

i want to add rows with matching user entered product code to jatable from the database . what this code does is thst it adds thr row but when i try to enter another row it replaces the previous row and adds the new one.. what changes should i make in this code to achieve that.

Comment: I'm far from being a java expert, but shouldn't `executeUpdate` be called with update/insert/delete statements?

Comment: can u help me here @trashgod